# Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) - Configure dynamic layer to not display all sub-layers?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

Using the example below, from the CMV, what would be the best way to not show the Fire Stations layer in the Louisville Public Safety map service assuming I wanted to see everything else and I wanted sublayertoggle true?

```
            type: 'dynamic',
            url: 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/PublicSafety/PublicSafetyOperationalLayers/MapServer',
            title: 'Louisville Public Safety',
            slider: true,
            noLegend: false,
            collapsed: false,
            sublayerToggle: true, //true to automatically turn on sublayers
            options: {
                id: 'louisvillePubSafety',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                imageParameters: imageParameters
            },
            identifyLayerInfos: {
                layerIds: [2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 21]
            }
```

I've added these 3 lines after the declaring and setting of `imageParameters`:

`var imageParameters2 = new ImageParameters();
    imageParameters2.layerIds = [1];
    imageParameters2.layerOption = ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_EXCLUDE;`

and changed `imageParameters: imageParameters` to `imageParameters: imageParameters2` in the layer config but the Fire Station layer still shows up.

Comment: CMV related questions are better answered in their own forum in [GitHub](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues)

Answer (score 1):

CMV does not support the exclusion of a dynamic service layer.
You have to make some changes.

1. config\viewer.js
   add layerControlLayerInfos
    identifyLayerInfos: {
           layerIds: [2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 21]
           },
           layerControlLayerInfos: {
           visibilityLayerInfos: [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
           } //the layer with id 1 is not present
2. gis\dijit\LayerControl\controls\Dynamic.js
   modify the _createSublayers function:
   [image]
3. gis\dijit\LayerControl\plugins\legendUtil.js
    modify the _createDynamicSublayerLegendfunction:
   [image]

Now, the CMV support the exclusion of a dynamic service layer.