# CMV LayerControl Hide Dynamic sub-layers

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I was trying to use the solution on this thread and my I am unable to get it to work. Specifically, layer._hideLayersInLegend does not exist anywhere in the scope of the LegendControl of my version of CMV, it is undefined. Do I need to add this somewhere?

[CMV Configure Dynamic Layer to not display all sub layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122704/configurable-map-viewer-cmv-configure-dynamic-layer-to-not-display-all-sub-l/122872#122872)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the answer you pointed to actually solved the problem or not - Only because I've never reviewed it or tested it.

Look at [issue 347](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/347) in the CMV GitHub repo for some more recent discussion. In that discussion I provided a solution (more of a work-around) by using CSS to hide the DOM node for the particular sub layer(s) like this:

```
div#louisvillePubSafety-4-sublayer-control {
    display: none;
}
```

You'll need to combine that with setting the ImageParameters for the layer you want shown. There is a link to that in the discussion I referenced. Here is a direct link: [issue 198](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/198)

Comment: Thanks, those posts help with what I was trying to figure out.