# CMV Viewer dynamic layer show sub layer

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I'm customizing the cmv viewer to works with my services.
I have service that have 3 layer (0,1,2) and is a dynamic map service layer.
It's possible to set only one layer to show?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only allow the user to choose one layer, for example layer id 1, I think you will want to use the [Image Parameters class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/imageparameters-amd.html).

Create a function in your config file (viewer.js)

```
// Allows user to hide layers in Dynamic map service
function buildImageParameters (config) {
   var ip = new ImageParameters();
   for (var key in config) {
       if (config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           ip[key] = config[key];
       }
   }
   return ip;
}
```

And in your dynamic layer options:

```
imageParameters: buildImageParameters({
               format: 'png32',
               layerIds: [1],
               layerOption:  ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_EXCLUDE
            })
```

This will allow you to only show one layer in the app from that service.

[Details Here](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/404)

[Or modify cmv to allow this directly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122704/configurable-map-viewer-cmv-configure-dynamic-layer-to-not-display-all-sub-l/122872#122872)